# How to reporting bugs (most efficient way) on launchpad?

Tags: launchpad, bug-reporting

I have bug with my huawei EC1260-2 modem connecting into ubuntu 14.04 beta2. It detect my modem but it cannot establish the connection and the bug dialog doesn't appear. It runs fine on ubuntu 12.04 - 13.10
So how the most efficient (and maybe easiest) way for reporting the bug to launchpad?

Comment: Ah yes thank you.
we can pressing Alt + F2 then type ubuntu-bug pakagename or ubuntu-bug -w. But what should I do because i dont know the name of pakage and it doesnt have window.
I have trying with sending an email to new@bugs.launchpad.net but it rejected because i dont mention the pakage name.
The problem is after the modem detected by usb-modeswitch, it can't establish the connection. When I use mobile partner, the dialog suddenly appear message "the device has been disconnected or unavailable", whereas the network manager show that the modem isn't disconnected but it fail to connecting.

Comment: Hoho, installing wasn't problem for me. I'm not talking about the problem of mobile partner.
Mobile partner itself has integrated with ubuntu system I thougt. Cause when the network-manager (nm) show the avalability of connection, the mobile partner are active too (sometimes mobile partner replacing nm so that nm-aplet for modem doesnt show up), the problem is I cannot establish connection trough network-manager nor mobile partner cause after modem detected, it automatically disconnected but still show up on network manager (In mobile partner signal doesnt show and 'connect' button are greyed)

Comment: Maybe I make a new thread???

Comment: I make a new question here http://askubuntu.com/questions/445109/network-manager-detect-my-modem-but-it-cannot-establish-connetion-cause-the-mode